# get() and peek() help for storing large numbers

Tags: c++, input, cin

I am having trouble with the cin.peek() and cin.get() functions. Input in general always eludes me. Basically, I am trying to be able to get a string of digits (that can be longer than an int which is why it uses characters) to insert into the MyInt object using the overload for >>. The MyInt class that I wrote has a dynamic char array in it called myNumber. The resize function does just that, resizes the dynamic array to a new size.

I need to do two things

1. Ignore leading whitespace
2. Stop at the next character that isn't 0-9. (whitespace, letters)

Here is what I have:

```
istream& operator>> (istream& s, MyInt& n)
// Overload for the input operator                                                                                             
{
  char c;             // For peeking                                                                                           
  int x;
  MyInt input;        // For storing                                                                                           
  unsigned int counter = 0; // counts # of stored digits                                                                       

  while (isspace(s.peek()))
  {
    c = s.get();
  }

  while (C2I(s.peek()) != -1)
  {
    x = C2I(s.get());
    input.myNumber[counter] = I2C(x);
    counter++;
    input.Resize(counter);
  }
  cout << "WHAH WHAH WEE WAH\n";

  n = input;
}
```

Main is calling just this:

```
cout << "Enter first number: ";
cin >> x;
cout << "Enter second number: ";
cin >> y;

cout << "You entered:\n";
cout << "  x = " << x << '\n';
cout << "  y = " << y << '\n';
```

Here is an output I got:

```
Enter first number: 14445678954333
WHAH WHAH WEE WAH
Enter second number: 1123567888999H
WHAH WHAH WEE WAH
You entered:
  x = 111111111111113
  y = 11111111111119
```

I am a student and this is 'homework'. So as with all homework, I am given illogical things I cannot access. This one being the string class. This is a pretty minor part of the work, but its like a thorn in my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say run it in the debugger and find out where you mess up the array, I would guess the resize.

since your input and output follow a pattern.

```
14445678954333
111111111111113

1123567888999H
11111111111119
```

You are one too long and the first and last number match.

Answer (score 1):

Why not always use a **std::string** to read and write your numbers ?

Then all you need is conversion from **MyInt** <-> **std::string**

```
class MyInt
{
    vector<int> Integers;
public:
    MyInt( const string& source )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < source.size(); ++i )
        {
            Integers.push_back( source[i] - '0' );
        }
    }

    MyInt()
    {
    }

};

istream& operator>> (istream& s, MyInt& n)
{
    string input;
    s >> input;
    n = input;
    return s;
}

int main()
{

    MyInt input;
    cout << "Enter first number: ";
    cin >> input;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Didn't mention it, but I did tag this 'homework'. So as with all homework, I am given illogical things I cannot access. This one being the string class. I'll edit the main.